# Multiple queries or can be done in one?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not very experienced with more advanced MySQL query stuff.. (mostly basic queries, return and parse response..etc)

However.. I am not clear on the correct approach when I need multiple things (responses) from the database.. Is there a way to get these things from the single query? or do I need to do a new query for each time?

Background:
I use PDO to do a SELECT statement

ie:

```
$getAllVideos_sql = "SELECT * as FROM $tableName WHERE active IS NOT NULL OR active != 'no' ORDER BY topic, speaker_last, title;";
$getAllVideos_stmt = $conn->prepare($getAllVideos_sql);
$getAllVideos_stmt->execute();
$getAllVideos_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results = $getAllVideos_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//parse as I see fit
```

This gives me my 'chunk of data' that I can pick apart and display as I want.

However.. I want to also be able to give some stats (totals)

For the total (distinct) 'topics'..  as well as total count for the 'titles' (should all be unique by default)

Do I need to do another query, prepare, execute, setFetchMode, fetch all over again?

Is this the proper way to do this?  Or is there a way to crib off the initial commands that are already in play?

To be clear, I'm not really looking for a query...   I'm looking to understand the proper way one does this.. when they need several pieces of data like I do?  multiple queries and executions..etc?

Or maybe it can and -should- be done in one snippet?   With an adjustment to the query itself to return sub select/queries info?

- this isnt the correct syntax, because it only returns 1 record..(but the total topic count seems to be correct, even though I only get 1 record returned)

  SELECT *, count(DISTINCT topic)as totalTopics, count(DISTINCT title)as totalTitles FROM $tableName;

Maybe this the more proper approach?  Try to include these totals/details in the main query to pick out?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get anything very clean that'll do this, however something like this might work:

```
SELECT * from $Table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Topic) as TotalTopics FROM $Table 
) s ON 1 = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Title) as TotalTitles FROM $Table 
) f ON 1 = 1
WHERE ( Active IS NOT NULL ) AND Active != 'no'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it seems to work with an updated query (I had syntax errors) without any JOINS..  
  
`$getAllVideos_sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT count(DISTINCT (topic)) FROM $tableName WHERE active = 'Active') as totalTopics, (SELECT count(DISTINCT (title)) FROM $tableName WHERE active = 'Active') as totalTitles FROM $tableName WHERE active IS NOT NULL OR active = 'Active' ORDER BY topic, speaker_last, title;";`

However.. I can NOT target my sub-query -as- values?  
This doesnt work for example: $results['totalTopics']

How can I get these values from my query?

Comment: Depending on how you get the information out, $results may not be in the structure you're expecting.   Try `var_dump($results)` to see what came back in $results

Answer (score 0):

Especially with web applications, many people are regularly doing counts or other aggregations somewhere along the way.  Sometimes if it is a global context such as all topics for all users, having some stored aggregates helps rather than requerying all record counts every time.

Example.  If you have a table with a list of "topics", have a column in there for uniqueTitleCount.  Then, based on a trigger, when a new title is added to a topic, the count is automatically updated by adding 1.  You can pre-populate this column by doing a correlated update to said "topics" table, then once the trigger is set, you can just have that column.

This also works as I see many times that people want "the most recent".  If your system has auto-increment IDs in the tables, similarly, have the most recent ID created for a given topic, or even most recent for a given title/document/thread so you don't have to keep doing something like.

```
select documentID, other_stuff
   from sometable 
   where documentID in ( select max( documentID ) 
                           from sometable 
                           where the title = 'something' )
```

Use where these make sense then your optimization pull-downs get easier to handle.  You could even have a counter per document "title" and even a most recent posting date so they can quickly be sorted based on interest, frequency of activity, whatever.

Comment: Here is my current attempt:  
  
`SELECT *, (SELECT count(DISTINCT (topic)) as totalTopics FROM $tableName WHERE active = 'Active'), (SELECT count(DISTINCT (title)) as totalTitles FROM $tableName WHERE active = 'Active') FROM $tableName WHERE active IS NOT NULL OR active = 'Active' ORDER BY topic, speaker_last, title;`  

however, when I loop through my $results... at the end of each line, I see this:

Comment: Continued:  

`foreach($results as $key => $value) { `....etc
  
.............`active:Active    (SELECT count(DISTINCT (topic)) as totalTopics FROM vimeo_videos WHERE active = 'Active'):16    (SELECT count(DISTINCT (title)) as totalTitles FROM vimeo_videos WHERE active = 'Active'):76   `

instead of a KEY.. I see my subquery text??  How can I access these values from a 'key' that has the name of my subquery text?

Comment: @whispers, don't do comments like this.  Edit your original post, put the details there, then just have a comment stating... hey. please check the updated post for clarification (or something similar).  Otherwise, you lose all the formatting advantages and others to see progress of details as available.